# Excel custom cell formatting: unexpected behavior?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've just noticed that when trying to use a custom formatting for, say, 16-digit credit card number, something really strange occurs:

[Screen Recording](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6FcD8kvdA9mlsbXL5C_oFUmw2Z?e=nLfadw)

Can someone explain what's happening and why it keeps defaulting to the special formatting?  And how can this be mitigated?

Note: I guess the mouse pointer doesn't get recorded in screen capture, so please ignore the pauses.

Comment: What's the unexpected behavior?

Comment: After applying the custom formatting, then returning to the cell formatting screen, the cell format has automatically changed to one of the Special grouping's format?

Answer (score 0):

The custom number format that you entered corresponds to the special format that appears when you re-select the cell.  That will happen whenever you enter any previously defined format.

Comment: And this is a predefined format that ships with Excel?  Is there no way to diable or remove it?

Comment: Why would you want to remove it?  In any event, it's not doing anything since you are entering your value as a text string.